# Addition of two scores, where one always override the other in the total score

Tags: missing-data, ranking

I have a problem I can't wrap my head around and I fear it has a simple solution :-) Apologies if this is the wrong site to ask this question.

I have data as the following

```
A  B
55 25
35 12
12 NA
6  12
2  53
NA 69
NA 66
NA 45
NA 43
NA 2

df <- data.frame(A = c(12,35,55,2,6,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), B = c(NA,12,25,53,12,2,66,45,69,43))
```

I want to calculate a third variable, C that equals A when A is not NA. When A is NA then C should equal B, BUT the C score should always follow that a row with A=NA should never outrank a row with A not equal to NA.

C can be any arbitrary number.